# Spring Batch More Partition Issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am developing the project by using spring partition.Usually we will load huge file and creating 20 thread in spring partition.

Is any limitation or disadvantage is there by creating more thread.Because for small file also we are creating 20 thread.

can u suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Thread creation is always expensive.
That's why it is important the concept of the Thread Pool, which basically means that you have a certain number of threads created at the startup waiting to be used.

This way, when you use the thread, you don't have to wait (as long as there are still threads remaining in the pool)

In a Spring application, normally you have to configure the thread pool by using a TaskExecutor.

So, in my opinion, it is more important that you have the pool under control (knowing and configuring the pool size) than to be worried about the relation of threads and file sizes.

If you want a better answer, please update with information about what is your pool configuration.

Comment: <batch:step id="master">
           <partition step="slave" partitioner="batchPartitioner">
             <handler grid-size="20" task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="20"/>
            </partition>
        </batch:step>